# Elastic search : Quesry not executing

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is mapping of my elastic search

```
{"MYAPP":{"mappings":{            
            "XX":{
                "_ttl":{"enabled":true},
                "properties":{"propX":{"type":"integer"}}
             },
            "YY":{
                "_ttl":{"enabled":true},
                "properties":{"propY":{"type":"integer"}}
             },
          }
    }
}
```

I want execute query like 
    `propX:XYZ AND propY:ABC`

The problem is if i do this

```
propX:XYZ AND propY:ABC
```

It return nothing, but this

```
propX:XYZ
```

return result. I think the problem is `propX` and `propY` are two different region thats why using both returns nothing.

Here is my JAVA code:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("MYAPP")
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("propX:XYZ AND propY:ABC")).execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your mapping, the `propX` and `propY` are located in different mapping types.

Assume you follow the index mapping. Each mapping type has it own document, in other word, all document inside type `XX` only have the `propX` field. And all document inside type `YY` only have the `propY` field.

So there is no document, that have the two fields in the same time and this is why you cannot find any document.

Comment: So to get result for `propX:XYZ AND propY:ABC` shall i put both field under same `_type`?

Comment: Because you use the query to find the document, but there is no such a document has the two fields and it's meaningless. So yes, if the two fields are properties of one item, just put them into same type. The different types are usually used to distinguish different logical data for your own need or data structure requirements.

Comment: BTW, you can think the `type` as a database table. This can be much "imageable".